# Storing passed property value in a variable to be used in another function

Tags: node.js, jestjs, axios

I wanted to pass the property value I used in my HTTP POST request so I can use it in another test.

---

```
const device = `28` + (new Date().getTime())
describe('register device', () => {
  test('create device registration', async () => {
    try {
      const registerDevice= await axios.post(`${baseUrl}register`, {
        deviceId: (`${deviceId}`),
        platformId: 'ios',
        osVersion: '11.0'
      }, {
        timeout,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenGenerator.generateAuthToken({
            name: 'namehere'
          })}`
        }
      })
      expect(registerDevice.status).toBe(200)
})
})
```

---

I wanted to pass the same value I used for the deviceId from the POST request above so I can put it on the payload for my next POST request. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You are already using it in first post like '${deviceId}' so same you can use for other post request also

Comment: yup. but if im going to use it in another function, it will get the initial value const device = `28` + (new Date().getTime()) -- which might have a different time when i posted the route.

Comment: no, `device` will be assigned the string value which is the result of the expression, eg `281511353142984`, it will not change. For it to change you would have to assign a function like `const device = () => `28` + (new Date().getTime());` and call it accordingly wherever needed.

Comment: thanks for the help!